# Query multiple post types - Order by type and post title title

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, order

I have three custom post types which I need to retrieve posts for within one wp_query. I am seeking to return the posts in the order of post type, as well as by post title.

Within the question [Ordering Custom Post Types with WP_Query](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/392905/ordering-custom-post-types-with-wp-query/392910#392910) @birgire provided a fantastic function which allows me to return the posts in an order as defined by an array within the post_type variable.

But I would also like to ensure that these posts are also ordered by post title. So my return would look something like this...

```
Cats - British Shorthair
Cats - Maine Coon
Cats - Siamese
Dogs - German Shepherd
Dogs - Labrador
Rabbits - Flemish
Rabbits - Holland Lop
Rabbits - Netherland Dwarf
```

I am unfamiliar with @birgire 's function and the FIELD part of it. Is it easily extendable to allow for post title sorting also?

Comment: Glad to see you got it covered by a great answer by Sally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is, and to also sort by the post title, you would just need to add `, {$wpdb->posts}.post_title <ASC or DESC>` after the [`FIELD()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field), like so which results in a clause that looks like `ORDER BY FIELD(wp_posts.post_type, <types>), wp_posts.post_title ASC`:

```php
// Replace this:
return $orderby       = "FIELD( {$wpdb->posts}.post_type," . $post_type__in_string . ' )';

// with this:
return $orderby       = "FIELD( {$wpdb->posts}.post_type," . $post_type__in_string . ' )' . // wrapped
    ", {$wpdb->posts}.post_title ASC";
```

But as for sorting the posts by the post type, if you do **not** actually need to sort the posts in the same order you have them in the *`post_type` array*, then you could simply use an [`orderby`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters) array like so:

```php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array( 'post', 'cats', 'dogs', 'rabbits' ),
    'orderby'   => array(
        'post_type'  => 'ASC', // Sort by the post type.
        'post_title' => 'ASC', // Then, by the post title.
    ),
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

- With the above example, the posts would be sorted like so:

  - Cats A
  - Cats B
  - Dogs A
  - Dogs B
  - *Post A*
  - *Post B*
  - Rabbits A
  - Rabbits B

  I.e. You would get `cats, dogs, post, rabbits` instead of `post, cats, dogs, rabbits` (note the `post` which is the first item in the `post_type` array).

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly. I really appreciate you including a reference link for **FIELD()**, as I did not realise that was a MySQL reference and was getting hung up on it. I also appreciate your additional bit about how I could extend **orderby** if custom post type sorting were not strictly required.